# Unable to locate switch on network

Tags: networking, configuration, hp, switch, configuration-management

I have a HP 2530-8G on the network which we cannot log in to as we do not know the management IP address. The MAC address does not appear in any of the DHCP leases so I would assume it is using a static IP. Nor does it appear in any IP scans (e.g. Angry IP) and from another switch of the same model, I cannot see any way to hide it from ICMP requests.
Attempts to connect via the management ports have also resulted in failure. The Micro USB connection requires the use of a terminal emulator (such as KiTTY) but all attempts have failed and I do not have a laptop with a serial port.

So, I cannot find its MAC address anywhere I look nor can I find the IP address. How do I connect to the management interface to find out how this switch is configured?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: If the switch doesn't have a management address configured, then you will need to connect to the console. Switches are transparent devices, and they will work, even without a configured management address.

Comment: My problems with connecting to the management console are outlined in the post.

Comment: I understand that, but if there is not management address configured on the switch, then the console connections is the only option.

Comment: `I do not have a laptop with a serial port.` - Purchase a USB to Serial adapter. - https://www.amazon.com/TRENDnet-Converter-Installation-Universal-TU-S9/dp/B0007T27H8

Comment: Rich, your question about HP switch firmware got locked so I can't comment on it but you should see this :) - anyway I just went right to it on the HPE website and found this; https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=JE005A Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Chopper. I now have another problem though...the newer firmware seems to have killed the switch :(

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

1. The 2530 series have a USB console port - connect a terminal, log in and run `show ip`.
2. On a computer connected directly to the switch, run a packet capture and look for LLDP packets. You should also be able to see the info from another switch supporting LLDP. (HP: `show lldp info remote`) By default, the 2530 announces itself every 30 s. The LLDP info includes the local management address.

On Windows, you can do a quick ARP scan running this script. It expects a parameter like `192.168.0` to scan 192.168.0.x.

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1,1,254) do (
  ping -n 1 -w 0 %1.%%i >nul
  arp -a %1.%%i|find "dynami"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to find the IP of the device.

Either you can use a tool like arp-scan to find all IP addresses in a range or you could start a packet capture, for example with wireshark, plug in and look at the ARP broadcasts.

Comment: Thanks. Is arp-scan a PowerShell command or a downloadable utility?

Comment: I have Wireshark too so I'll give that a go.

Comment: @RichM arp-scan is a linux tools.

Comment: Ah, that'll be why it didn't work then! Had a blast with Wireshark and can see lots of 'HewlettP_xx:xx:xx sources on the ARP broadcasts but nothing which matches the MAC of the switch.

Comment: Just tried the arp-scan command in Debian 9: "arp-scan: command not found"

Comment: OK, so I got arp-scan installed (not a lot of experience with Linux) but now I get a "Segmentation error". Should be noted I'm running this in a VM with bridged NIC.